# Handlebars 2.0 amd runtime returns undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js

I need help figuring out whats wrongs with the handlebars.runtime.amd.js

- The first weird thing I noticed, is the different folder structure I get when installing 
  Handlebars 2.0 using bower vs the one I get using NPM (Yes both of them were ~2.0)

My RequireJS path for the runtime module is as listed below. The path is 100% correct since I see the proper file loading in the dev tools network tab.

```
  paths:   {
    "handlebars": "../../node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.runtime.amd",
  },
```

In either package (bower / npm) when I include the runtime amd module the argument in the require callback is "undefined"..

```
require(["app", "handlebars"], function(app, h) {
  // why is 'h' undefined?? 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `handlebars.runtime.amd.js` exports named module **`handlebars.runtime`**. Require it with this name or use `handlebars.runtime.js` which is also could be used as AMD module but has no predefined name.